# OBJECT JSON Invalid - PLS-00488: 'JSON_VALUE' is it be a type - ORACLE 19C

Tags: json, oracle19c, json-table

I migrated my Oracle to version 19C and the job JSON command : create or replace type json_value_array as table of json_value; Get me a error : PLS-00488: 'JSON_VALUE' invalid variable declaration object must be a type or subtype

in the ORACLE 12C the job is valid ... question : in the new version this command is not valid? Do you have one solution ?

Could you help me please

thanks
Leandro Barbosa
Brasil IT

I'm reading the manual json-developers-guide oracle 19C and i did'n find any soluction.